# JQuery Selector that has

Tags: jquery, select

I'm trying to wrap my head around this.  e.g. Let's say I wanted to select #cp-Rollup, the first one.  (sorry about my question title.  Not sure how to word it)

```
$('.stats-tabs-position[href*="#cp-Rollup"]').click(function() {
        alert("cp-Rollup");
        });


                <ul class="stats-tabs-position">
                    <li class="settings-tabs"><a href="#cp-Rollup">Rollup</a></li>
                    <li class="settings-tabs"><a href="#cp-Vehicle">Vehicle</a></li>
                    <li class="settings-tabs"><a href="#cp-Personnel">Personnel</a></li>
                    <li class="settings-tabs"><a href="#cp-LogisticsRole">Logistics Role</a></li>
                    <li class="settings-tabs"><a href="#cp-LogisticsClass">Logistics Class</a></li>
                </ul>
```

Comment: could you not just use `$('#cp-Rollup').click()`?

Comment: You can't do that because he's trying to select the anchor that has an href='#cp-Rollup', not the element with id='cp-Rollup'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the anchor (a) element before the [href* like this:

```
$('.stats-tabs-position a[href*="#cp-Rollup"]').click(function() {
    alert("cp-Rollup");
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SZFyN/

Comment: +1 ( to the OP: ) taking in mind that you can have a *partial* naming in that case too: `a[href*="Rollup"]` thanks to the 'asterix *'

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.stats-tabs-position a[href="#cp-Rollup"]').click(function() {
    alert("cp-Rollup");
});
```